# Why do people (or bots) spam a site with comments when its obvious that they end up being blocked?

Tags: seo, wordpress, spam

Whenever I visit the Admin page of my WordPress site, I always find about 1000 new spam messages waiting there for me.

The question is what is the motivation for people (or bots) to spam a site with comments when its obvious that anti-spam WordPress plugins are bound to catch them and filter them out?

Comment: Not everyone uses that plug in. When it's automated you've got nothing to lose.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding SEO, the motivation of spammers is to take advantage of your site to earn SEO value (by posting a link) to their sites.

Here are possible reasons you get spams you're talking about:

1. **spam from human**
   A spammer can try to put a link to his website by posting a comment to see if your site auto-validate comments (if not, this spammer very probably won't come back to your site)
2. **spam from bots**
   Spam from bots generally come from automatic software which get some URL from the web (by searching for a keyword entered by a spammer) and put comment on all found URLs.
   On this case, the spammer try to use a generic text to comment all these URLs and don't analyze target websites. 
   If the spammer is lucky, your site auto-validate comment or Akismet don't detect the ocmment as spam or you validate the comment. In that case, the spammer get a link.
   If the spammer is unlucky, the comment is considered as spam and won't never be published but whatever! By using a software (bot), the spammer try to get a link from so many URLs on a little time.
   And the problem is the spammer always get some links with this kind of techniques.